# How to convert sql to jpql

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, jpql

I want to convert the following oracle sql query to jpql. I have created entity for DC_Subjects and SUBJECT_SERIAL_NUMBER is a column in DC_Subjects. I know how to convert sql to jpql when the entity model for the table exists. But in this case I have made use of dual, rownum etc. I dont know how to covert it to jpql.

SQL query:

```
select n from
    ( select rownum n from dual connect by level <= (select max(SUBJECT_SERIAL_NUMBER) + 2  from DC_Subjects))
    where n >= 3000 minus (select subject_Serial_Number from DC_Subjects where version_End = '31-DEC-3099 12.00.00.000000000 AM');
```

Comment: The query has a lot of Oracle specifics. You can try to use JPA native query facilities and leave the query as it is.

Comment: Any JPQL reference would tell you that you cannot when there is no equivalent entity etc, and the functions used are not part of JPQL.

Comment: @garfield  and Billy Thanks for the response. Will try with native query.